# Boolean always returning true in Async Function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, boolean

Why is my function always returning true?

I expected the program to return true about half of the time and result in the anwering machine call the other half of the time.

Also, is there a better way to write this code? any tips would be much appreciated!

I'm just learning.

```js
const friends = ["John", "Sue", "Matt", "Tim", "Sara", "Lucy"];

const randomFriend = () => {
  return friends[Math.floor(Math.random() * friends.length)];
};
const randomNumber = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) < 5;
};

const ring = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("ring ring ring");
    }, 2000)
  );
};

const machine = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("sorry, we are not available to answer your call.");
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const answer = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Hey, this is BRandon. May I ask who is calling?`);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const reply = async (friend) => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`this is ${friend}.`);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const call = async () => {
  if (randomNumber) {
    const friend = randomFriend();
    console.log(randomNumber);
    console.log(`I think I will call ${friend}`);
    await ring();

    answer();
    reply(friend);
  } else {
    const friend = randomFriend();
    console.log(`I think I will call ${friend}`);
    await ring();

    machine();
  }
};
call();
```

Comment: `if (randomNumber) {` — `randomNumber` is a function, not a boolean. If you **called** the function (which you don't) then it would *return* a boolean.

Comment: Agreed with Quentin above. You need to call the function, `if (randomNumber())`.

Comment: Also note that unless you want their logic running in parallel (though never simultaneously), you need to `await` the promise you get from `answer()` before calling `reply(/*...*);` (etc.). Separately, `answer`, `ring`, `machine`, and `reply` all `await` promises that are never settled (neither fulfilled nor rejected). I suggest reading up a bit more on promises and async functions ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) is good; I also [wrote a book](https://thenewtoys.dev), see Chapters 8 and 9).

Answer (score -1):

```
 const call = async () => {
  if (randomNumber()) {
    const friend = randomFriend();
    console.log(`I think I will call ${friend}`);
    await ring();

    answer();
    reply(friend);
  } else {
    const friend = randomFriend();
    console.log(`I think I will call ${friend}`);
    await ring();

    machine();
  }
};
```